# Maximum Sublist Length (Prolog) - No cuts or logical Prolog built-ins

Tags: prolog

I am beginner to Prolog ...
What I want to do is similar to a `transpose`, but without using any cuts or logical Prolog built-ins.
Also, if a list does not have any elements, its tuple entry should be `[]`.
Like say I have a list `my_pred([[a , b , c], [1, 2]], Y)`.
This should output:

```
Y = [[a ,1], [b, 2], [c , []]]
```

Here it adds `[]` if sublist is smaller comparing with length of the largest sublist during transpose.

I am looking for a beginner friendly yet working solution which can enhance understanding of beginners like me :)
I tried to search, but so far all solutions used cuts or some logical Prolog built-ins :(

I did not find a solution to my question anywhere so far...

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? And your question title seems a bit off. Nowhere in your question are you asking about a list length. Actual determination of the list length may not be involved at all in the question or the solution. But you really should at least go through a Prolog tutorial. You have basic syntax issues with `my_pred_func[[[a , b , c] [1, 2]], Y]`.

Comment: I am going through prolog tutorial right now :) And no it isn't a home work.  I managed to make a similar function in Scheme. But I am having a hard time converting it to Prolog :( I know the process basically but I needed some help like what could be simplest solution with our using any logical Prolog built in or any cuts. Understating solution could also help me learning lists , sublists well I think.

Comment: In Prolog, you want to think recursively when it comes to lists. Think of predicates as *rules* that declare a relationship rather than a *function* that performs a task. I wouldn't call it `my_pred_func`. And Prolog is smart about matching (unifying). So you can have a predicate head, `zip_lists([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [[X,Y]|T]) :- ...` (you fill in). Based upon how you want to handle empty lists, you want more than one base case: `zip_lists([], [], []).` (trivial case), `zip_lists([X|Xs], [], [[X,[]]|T]) :- ...` (you fill in), and `zip_lists([], [Y|Ys], [[[],Y]|T]) :-...` (you fill in).

Comment: Since your goal is to learn, I gave you hints in my prior comment rather than to just post an answer with a solution. See if you can do it from the hints. It is a very simple solution, and doesn't need cuts or list processing built-ins. :) Also, try Googling "99 Prolog Problems" which have lots of exercises with answers that illustrate many basic principles, especially recursive list handling.

Comment: My question is if I know number of elements ( sublist) its fine , but how do I think if it is for n sublists of n length ? It should work correct for any number of sublists of different lengths. Like if maximum length is 4, min length is anything less than max length , then I need to fill up smaller sublist in transposed result with empty '[] that many number of times. This is my approach but I don't know how to think for n sublists :(

Comment: When you do the recursion, you don't need to know the length. The recursion and the base cases handle it for you. The recursion ends at the base cases. It's more complex and more work to try to do this in terms of lengths. Don't worry about the lengths. Look where I have `...` in my hints, and write a recursive definition that calls `zip_lists` again on the tails, which are shorter lists. Recursion will just end properly on the base cases when the list is exhausted. This is not just a Prolog principle, but would be true of any recursive function on an enumerable type.

Comment: Did you Google the 99 Prolog Problems like I suggested to see examples of list processing? If you study a few, you'll get the idea.

Comment: I will try ... thanks !

Comment: I tried but getting overwhelmed :( ... I am sort of scared it seems too complex ... Maybe somebody can share some useful material ..I always get lost in code ... I am sorry but I am saying the way I am feeling right now .

Comment: Maybe you trace out of some base case ... So that I could understand via debug if needed how does recursion help me not worry about lengths.